# mod_rewrite - old parameter name to new name

Tags: mod-rewrite, parameters

Hi all I need a bit of getting a redirect working in mod_rewrite.

I need to redirect the following

```
http://mysite.com/dictionary/find?word=test
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/dictionary/find?w=test
```

I'm sure the solution is trivial enough but my knowledge of mod_rewrite and regular expressions is quite limited and I haven't been able to work out. This is what I have attempted so far to no avail.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} word= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)word=(\w+)/$ /w=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should be sufficient for you...

RewriteRule (?|&)word=(\w+) $1w=$2

this will replace it even if combined with other parameters.Your attempt to only process the querystring is interesting, I have never used that and cannot answer to if it's possible.

As a sidenote, turn on:

RewriteLog      "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
  RewriteLogLevel 2

for more useful feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help jishi

I have tried your RewriteRule but I'm getting the following error trying to start Apache with it in place

RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '(?|&)word=(\\w+)'

The extra backslash is not a mistake on my part, it just prints out that way.

Comment: Just so I'm clear the full error is:
Syntax error on line 2 of /data/home/user/web/conf/rewrite.conf:
RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '(?|&)query=(\\w+)'

Comment: hm you might need to escape the ?, (\?|&)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)word=(.*)
RewriteRule ^dictionary/find$ $0?%1w=%3 [R=301,L]
```