# mod_rewrite to change query string parameter name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, querystringparameter

I need help writing a mod rewrite rule to change the name of a query string parameter. I want to change the name, not the value.

old name `partner`
new name `a_aid`

so a link like this

```
http://domain.com/?partner=derphipster&pname=foo&plink=http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2Ffoo
```

will become

```
http://domain.com/?a_aid=derphipster&pname=foo&plink=http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2Ffoo
```

I found this article but the accepted answer generated errors for the OP:
[mod_rewrite - old parameter name to new name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569600/mod-rewrite-old-parameter-name-to-new-name)

also this article, but the solution was to use PHP. which will not work in my case:
[APACHE mod_rewrite change variable name in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451183/apache-mod-rewrite-change-variable-name-in-query-string)

I can't use PHP because some affiliate tracking code creates a cookie from the query string--and expects the a_aid. So I'm trying to convert `partner` into `a_aid` for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK think I hacked it together on my own. Please post an answer if you think its brittle or could be done better and I'll accept yours instead

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)partner(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1a_aid%2 [R=301,L]
```