# mod_rewrite: change a single query string parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

http://foo.bar/index.php?page=this-is-the-page

Now I have to find misspelled URLs with mod_rewrite like this:

http://foo.bar/index.php?page=this--is-the-page

unfortunally so far I wasn't able to find the correct **RewriteRule** :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)--((\w+)(-(\w+))*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?page=%1-%2
```

The problem seems to be the "?" which should mean QSD.
Anyway it was suggested this way in articles e.g. [mod_rewrite to change query string parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005384/mod-rewrite-to-change-query-string-parameter-name)

So, how can I reorganize the query string values with mod_rewrite only?  SEO-friendliness and hacking the PHP code is not an issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*?)--([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?page=%1-%2 [L,R]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Unfortunally I don't get why it works and what the main difference is. I assume it is the L-parameter? Could you explain it pls?

Comment: Problem is use of \w+ and .+ in your regex. You can try your regex in some online regex testers to verify this