# .htaccess - How to rename GET variable in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, get, rename

I have to rename a GET  variable in an URL from:

[https://example.com/dev/?id[dokid]=5](https://example.com/dev/?id%5Bdokid%5D=5)

to

[https://example.com/dev/?doc[dokid]=5](https://example.com/dev/?doc%5Bdokid%5D=5)

There are many examples for rewriting the parameter, but not for the name.
I' m a .htaccess newbie and need some advice...

Thx fxp

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess code in your question, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mod\_rewrite to change query string parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005384/mod-rewrite-to-change-query-string-parameter-name)

Answer (score 0):

I put this code into apache virtual host config:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "/dev/" [NC]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} id\[dokid\]=([-a-zA-Z0-9-&-=_+]+)
RewriteRule   ^/dev/$  /dev/?doc\[dokid\]\=%1   [R] [END]
```

This solution works perfect.